# Merge function in jdbc

Tags: jdbc

```
public static void merge() {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("LifeCycle");
        EntityManager em = null;
        try {
            em = emf.createEntityManager();
            System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");

            EmployeeEntity employee=new EmployeeEntity();
            employee.setEmpId(1002);
            //employee.setEmpId(1111);
            employee.setEmpLocation("Mysore");
            employee.setEmpName("Mahadeva");
            System.out.println("Before  merge   :  The EmployeeEntity instance is in MANAGED state  :" + em.contains(employee));
            em.merge(employee);
            System.out.println("After   merge   :  The EmployeeEntity instance is in MANAGED state  :" + em.contains(employee));

            em.getTransaction().begin();
            em.getTransaction().commit();
            System.out.println("After  Commit   :  The EmployeeEntity instance is in MANAGED state  :" + em.contains(employee));
            System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if(em!=null){
                em.close();
            }
            if (emf != null) {
                emf.close();

            }
        }
    }
```

For all three syso i get false as the output ,why? i don't understand, even when I write syso between begin() and commit then also it is giving false as the output.
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge works on the clone of the entity .
**It first copies the attributes of the clone into the unit of work copy and then that cloned entity is managed and not the original entity you passed.**
What you are expecting in your example is for `em.persist(entity)` operation. persist registers the entity without cloning.
 Try with `em.persist(entity)` and it should give you expected result.
**merge operation is provided for RMI objects and hence that behavior.**